# Abstract Factory for Dependency Inversion

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design, class-design

I have been reading up a bit on factories and builders and such, and one thing I noticed was that in most cases, the use of an abstract factory only seems to come up if the programmer has a specific need to create various implementations of an object.

My question is, can an abstract factory be used PURELY for it's dependency inversion benefit?

An example would be an abstract factory that has a single make method and only has a single type of object to create. Even though I don't need to create variations on this object, I still remove dependency on the concrete object implementation from the calling code. This seems like more than enough reason to use an abstract factory for creating basically any object in the whole application. I imagine this gets tedious, which I suppose is one reason to not go this route, but are there any other reasons?

Comment: Intent. In the GoF book there are some patterns that use exactly the same code, but they are different patterns because of intent. You can do what you state, but it wouldn't be an abstract factory any more, even if the code were identical, because the intent is different. And, it's tedious :)

Comment: If you need pure dependency injection, then just use DI. Abstract Factory only adds noise. I think Dependency Injection has mostly replaced the Abstract Factory pattern in modern software development.

Comment: Abstract factory is not meant for inversion of control (IOC). The IOC is obtained through the use of a Dependency Injector. There exists a lot of them for all the languages. If you tell us which programming language and framework you are using we can suggest you one.